# Ibatis Sequence Number Generation

Tags: mysql, spring, ibatis

I am new to Ibatis. How do I generate a sequence number using Ibatis and insert that number into a mysql table? The sequence number should start with 1000 so that it can be used as a primary key in the table. I am using spring, ibatis and mysql.

Comment: You should switch to MyBatis, as IBatis was moved to attic in 2010: http://attic.apache.org/projects/ibatis.html

Comment: Have you tried some of the ibatis docs? Page 20 of the Java tutorial mentions how to do a sequence number with Oracle and SQL server. Should be easy enough to switch to mysql. https://ibatis.apache.org/docs/java/pdf/iBATIS-SqlMaps-2_en.pdf

Comment: "The sequence number **should start with 1000 so that it can be used as a primary key** in the table"- even if ur sequence is starting form 1, still u can use it as primary key.

Answer (score 0):

As iBatis is dead since 2010, I presume MyBatis usage. With [MyBatis you can use these annotations to insert and retrieve primary key from DB and map both to a interface](https://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/java-api.html):

```
@Insert("insert into table2 (name) values(#{name})")
@SelectKey(statement="call identity()", keyProperty="nameId", before=false, resultType=int.class)
int insertTable2(Name name);
```